# How to use nested objects in TypeScript? Property does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql

I have a React/GraphQL small application working fine, and I'm trying to add TypeScript to it, as I'm new to TypeScript and trying to learn it. I have a GraphQL API endpoint that is returning products and information on those products. Using React, I'm storing products in a state and then rendering each product using JSX.

I created a type `Product` with the information that I expect the API to return, but it's also returning nested objects, and everything I tried triggers a TypeScript error. This is a simplified example of what the API is returning:

```
{
    "data": {
        "products": [
            {
                "productName": "Soda",
                "code": "sod",
                "prices": {
                    "nationalPrices": {
                        "localPrices": [
                            {
                                "pricePerUnit": "1.99"
                            }
                        ],
                        "regionalPrices": [
                            {
                                "pricePerUnit": "2.49"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "vendorPrices": {
                        "localPrices": [
                            {
                                "pricePerUnit": "1.49"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            // more products... 
        ]
    }
}
```

And this is the solution I currently have. `code`, `productName` and `prices` are working fine, but `nationalPrices` is triggering a TypeScript error `property nationalPrices does not exist on type 'object'`. What can I do to fix this error?

```
type nationalPricesObject = {
    localPrices: object[];
}

type Product = {
    code: string;
    productName: string;
    prices: object;
    nationalPrices: nationalPricesObject;
}


function ProductList() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState < Product[] > ([]);
    const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(LOAD_PRODUCTS);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
            setProducts(data.products);
        }
    }, [data]);

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                {products.map(p =>
                (
                    <div>
                        <ProductCard
                            productName={p.displayName}
                            code={p.code}
                            // simplified code below for sake of clearity 
                            pricePerUnit={p.prices.nationalPrices.localPrices[0]['pricePerUnit']}
                        />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Side note, you'll love this, saves all the hassle with typescript types when working with GraphQl... https://www.npmjs.com/package/@graphql-codegen/cli

Comment: In the template, you're referencing `product.prices.nationalPrices` which doesn't exist according to your types above. You typed `Product.prices` as just being a plain `object`. Following @James answer will fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product doesn't contain a `nationalPrices` property.  Product.prices does.  We can set a type Prices which contains the stuff expected in Product.prices, and use that to define the prices property of the Product object.

```
type Prices = {
    nationalPrices: nationalPricesObject;
    vendorPrices: someOtherPricesObject;
}

type Product = {
    code: string;
    productName: string;
    prices: Prices;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usage of `object` is tricky in typescript, and generally not recommended. You have two problems here:

1. `object` is an ambiguous type, so you cannot use `prices.nationalPrices` because `nationalPrices` does not exist on type `object`
2. Once you fix this, you will also encounter an error that `localPrices[0]` which is of type `object` does not have `pricePerUnit`

To fix these, make you types more specific:

```js
type nationalPricesObject = {
    localPrices: { pricePerUnit: number; }[]; // assuming this is number?
}

type Product = {
    code: string;
    productName: string;
    prices: nationalPricesObject;
}
```

Lastly, by convention, types in typescript should be `PascalCase`, and interfaces should be preferred. So, I would change your code to look like:

```js
interface Price {
  pricePerUnit: number;
}

interface NationalPrices {
    localPrices: Price[];
}

interface Product {
    code: string;
    productName: string;
    prices: NationalPrices;
}
```